# Installing Sklearn from Source on Windows 7

Tags: scikit-learn, installation, pip, python-3.4

I am on Windows 7 (64 bit) and have Python 3.4 installed along with the other stated required dependencies for the sklearn python package [NumPy (>= 1.6.1), SciPy (>= 0.9)].  I installed Numpy and SciPy from the .whl files I found online that matched python 3.4.  I am trying to install the sklearn package by calling `pip install sklearn` (FYI, I am trying to do this install without using Python (x.y) because I want python 3.x).  the `pip install sklearn` command will run for a while, but then I get the following error:

```
copying sklearn\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\sklearn\tests
running build_clib
customize MSVCCompiler
Missing compiler_cxx fix for MSVCCompiler
customize MSVCCompiler using build_clib
building 'libsvm-skl' library
compiling C sources
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Windows   SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279

----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\jjaaae\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-43xaawp2\\scikit-learn\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\jjaaae\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-7i3ghuri-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\jjaaae\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-43xaawp2\scikit-learn\
```

I have tried to install Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 as it describes in the error message.  I have also restarted the command prompt and my computer, but I still get this error message.  What am I missing?

Comment: other option is to install anaconda for windows, which installs all these packages at once without any hassle: https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  The download file for Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 allows you to "install" it even if you don't have .Net 4.x installed yet.  I must have gotten click happy during the install and missed that warning.  So the install for SDK 7.1 was really fast and didn't install what I needed.  When I backed up, installed Microsoft .NET Framework 4 from [this URL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851) first, then installed SDK 7.1 per instructions it worked.